# Activation of the tab menu at the scroll Spy

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, scrollspy

I increase the sentence for the first time. 
I made ​​a spy scroll to bootstrap. 
There is no problem in basic functions. However, with the scroll wheel on mouse 
When making a display, the timing of activation of the tab menu are different, respectively. 
For example, there is a tab menu named A, there is a tab menu named B, as well 
On the assumption that there is a title of B and A, and when the scroll wheel on mouse, A tab menu, this parameter will affect the activation of just above the title A, tab menu B is active in the above the title B of has changed. I want to solve this problem.

http://itspresent.co.kr/?page_id=466

Answer (score 0):

I belive if I understand you correctly, you are having issues with the offset. In your `<body>` code, put something similar to this:

```
<body id="body" class="page page-id-466 page-template-default page"  data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" data-offset="10">
```

Here is the webpage this is from in the 'Options' category, http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

You can change the number of the offset to any value you see fit.